# Как настроить пагинацию на сайте SEO-оптимизация

Tags: wordpress, seo

Нужна помощь, есть пагинация на сайте, но при переходе на вторую страницу получается следующее - https://domen.do/page/2/. Так вот, как оптимизировать это в плане SEO? Каноникал должен быть на первую страницу, а тайтл должен уникализироваться - в нем должно писаться, на подобии того, что страница 2, 3 и т.д. Использую YOAST SEO.

Answer (score 1):

Эта проблема довольно хорошо комментируется в руководстве Гугл **[5 распространенных ошибок при работе с атрибутом rel=canonical](https://developers.google.com/search/blog/2013/04/5-common-mistakes-with-relcanonical)** --> Ошибка 1. Добавление атрибута rel=canonical, указывающего на первую страницу из нескольких нумерованных. Однако русская версия по моему мнению довольно неуклюжая, поэтому я представляю мой перевод английской версии.

> Представьте, что у вас есть статья на нескольких страницах:
>
> ```
>  example.com/article?story=cupcake-news&page=1
>  example.com/article?story=cupcake-news&page=2
>  и так далее
> ```
>
> Указание rel = canonical со страницы 2 (или любой более поздней
> страницы) на странице 1 не является правильным использованием rel =
> canonical, поскольку это не дублирующиеся страницы. Использование rel
> = canonical в этом случае приведет к тому, что контент на страницах 2 и выше вообще не будет проиндексирован. Хороший контент (например,
> «печенье лучше питательных» и «для овощей») теряется при указании rel
> = canonical с компонентных страниц на первую страницу серии.

В другом руководстве **[Для чего вам нужно выбирать канонический URL](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/advanced/crawling/consolidate-duplicate-urls)** Гугл говорит:

> Выбрать каноническую страницу из числа одинаковых или похожих стоит по
> нескольким причинам:
>
> Чтобы указать, какой URL следует показывать в результатах поиска.

Таким образом для попадание всех содержаний ваших страниц в результата поиска используйте указание канонического линка для каждой страницы, которую вы хотите представить в результатах поиска, указывающего сам на себя.

Answer (score 0):

Частная проблема: тег rel = canonical используется не по назначению и не в тех ситуациях, где он действительно нужен, в итоге – нежелательные странички в индексе, проблемы с канибализацией запросов.

В данном посте хочу затронуть 2 вопроса:
– Какое решение выбрать для закрытия
– Как найти и промониторить возможные ошибки максимально быстро

Полезная инфо по софту внизу поста. Хороший материал по теме, комментарии Джона Мюллера из Google по этому вопросу.

Мета-тег noindex – официальная документация Google :

> «Вы можете предотвратить отображение страницы или другого ресурса в поиске Google, включив метатег noindex или заголовок в ответ HTTP. Когда робот Googlebot в следующий раз просканирует эту страницу и увидит тег или заголовок, он полностью исключит эту страницу из результатов поиска Google, независимо от того, ссылаются ли на нее другие сайты ».

Все, что делает тег noindex, – это исключает отображение этой страницы в результатах поиска Google.

Тег rel = canonical – официальная документация Google:

«Канонический URL-адрес – это URL-адрес страницы, которая, по мнению Google, является наиболее репрезентативной из набора повторяющихся страниц на вашем сайте. Например, если у вас есть URL-адреса для одной и той же страницы (example.com?dress=1234 и example.com/dresses/1234), Google выберет один из них как канонический ».

Т.е. это решение может объединить все сигналы ссылок и релевантности на одной странице. Но, Google рассматривает тег rel canonical как подсказку, нет никакой гарантии, что Google будет ему подчиняться, и алгоритм Google может решить показать какую-либо другую страницу в результатах поиска.

Цитата Мюллера по вопросу:

…если вы действительно не хотите, чтобы этот контент вообще отображался в поиске, я бы использовал noindex. Если вы предпочитаете, я действительно хочу, чтобы все было объединено на одной странице, и если будут отображаться отдельные, как и все, но большинство из них должно быть объединено, я бы использовал rel canonical…

Если задача – исключить из выдачи, то эффект будет один, но:
noindex – точно исключит из выдачи,
canonical – скорее всего, исключит.

Также можно использовать схему Rel Canonical и Noindex, это не является широко обсуждаемым решением, но, по словам Джона, это действенный способ борьбы, например, с дублирующимся контентом.